# Why GCC compiler omitting some code?

Tags: avr, c, avr-gcc, optimization, gcc

I can not understand why GCC compiler cutting out part of my code while it preserve absolutely the same one in the neighborhood?

The C code:

```
#define setb_SYNCO do{(PORTA|= (1<<0));} while(0);

ISR(INT0_vect){
    unsigned char i;

    i = 10;
    while(i>0)i--;   // first pause - omitted

    setb_SYNCO;
    setb_GATE;
    i=30;
    clrb_SYNCO;
    while(i>0)i--;  // second pause - preserved
    clrb_GATE;
}
```

The corresponding part of LSS (assembler file, created by the compiler):

```
ISR(INT0_vect){
  a4:   1f 92           push    r1
  a6:   0f 92           push    r0
  a8:   0f b6           in  r0, 0x3f    ; 63
  aa:   0f 92           push    r0
  ac:   11 24           eor r1, r1
  ae:   8f 93           push    r24
    unsigned char i;

    i = 10;
    while(i>0)i--;

    setb_SYNCO;
  b0:   d8 9a           sbi 0x1b, 0 ; 27
    setb_GATE;
  b2:   d9 9a           sbi 0x1b, 1 ; 27
    i=30;
    clrb_SYNCO;
  b4:   d8 98           cbi 0x1b, 0 ; 27
  b6:   8e e1           ldi r24, 0x1E   ; 30
  b8:   81 50           subi    r24, 0x01   ; 1
    while(i>0)i--;
  ba:   f1 f7           brne    .-4         ; 0xb8 <__vector_1+0x14>
    clrb_GATE;
  bc:   d9 98           cbi 0x1b, 1 ; 27
}
  be:   8f 91           pop r24
  c0:   0f 90           pop r0
  c2:   0f be           out 0x3f, r0    ; 63
  c4:   0f 90           pop r0
  c6:   1f 90           pop r1
  c8:   18 95           reti
```

I could assume that compiler figure out that such code is dummy and cuts it out but why is it preserve the same one in the end of the code?

Is there any compiler instructions to prevent from such optimization?

Comment: try to declare i as volatile too, i.e.  unsigned volatile char i;

Comment: Thank you, @VladimirCravero. Partially it worked. However my code grown significantly bigger as var `i` was allocated in RAM

Comment: You can also tell the compiler to not optimize a single function, maybe it's worth to try this method with your ISR. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9044490) question on stackoverflow.

Comment: Hey Roman, I added the "c" tag to your question removing atmega. I had to remove one tag since there's a limit (five), and when asking a code related question adding the language name as a tag is great because all code (Q&As) gets highlighted.

Comment: @VladimirCravero that's OK! Thank you for your input

Comment: Generally speaking, higher level languages (like C) are explicitly designed to *not* be bound to a 1:1 relationship with their resulting assembly.  If you need to count instructions to get the timing right, you always have to rely on assembly (as some of the answers did).  The whole point of high level languages is that the compiler has some freedom to help make your code faster-stronger-better than before. Details like register allocations and branch predictions are much better left to the compiler... except in times like this where you, the programmer, know exactly the instructions you want.

Comment: The better question is, why isn't GCC optimizing away *both* of those loops?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen definitely!

Comment: I would expect it to get rid of both, or maybe replace both with a direct assignment to zero. What are the definitions of the macros?

Comment: @Random832, I've added one macro definition to the initial answer. Others are very similar.

Comment: Gcc first unrolls the loop and only then notices that the corresponding code is useless. With a loop size of 30, unrolling would be foolish and gcc doesn't do it. At a higher optimization level both are optimized away.

Comment: It's because of flow analysis. You decrement `i` from `10` to `0`, but the updated value is never used: after the loop there is a _define_ (`i = 30`) but no _use_ (like `y = i + 1`). So whatever value `i` had before the `i = 30` part is not relevant. The `while` loop is marked as pointless and the corresponding code is not emitted.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo but i is a local variable and dies two lines after the second loop, and is never read. I'm putting my chips on Marc's explaination just above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since in one comment you state that "each CPU tick is worthy" I suggest using some inline assembly to make your delays loop just as you want. This solution is superior to the various `volatile` or `-O0` because it makes **clear** what your intent is.

```
unsigned char i = 10;
__asm__ volatile ( "loop: subi    %0, 0x01\n\t"
                   "      brne    loop"
                   : "+rm" (i)
                   : /* no inputs */
                   : /* no dirty registers to decleare*/);
```

That should do the trick. The volatile thing is there to tell the compiler "I know this does not do anything, just keep it and trust me". The three asm "statements" are quite self explanatory, you can use any register instead of r24, I believe the compiler likes lower registers so you might want to use a high one. After the first `:` you should list output (read and write) c variables, and there's none, after the second `:` you should list input (ronly) c variables, again, there is none, and the third parameter is a comma separated list of modified registers, in this case r24. I am not sure if you should include also the status register since the `ZERO` flag changes of course, I did not include it.

*edit* edited answer as OP requested. Some notes.

The `"+rm"` before `(i)` means that you are letting the compiler decide to place i in **m**emory or in a **r**egister. That's a good thing in most cases since the compiler can optimize better if it's free. In your case I believe you want to keep only the r constraint to force i to be a register.

Comment: Looks like this is a thing I really need. But could you modify your answer to accept any `c` variable instead of literal `10` I mentioned in the original answer? I'm trying to read the GCC manuals regarding the proper use of __asm__ construction but it's a bit obscured for me now. I'd be very appreciate!

Comment: @RomanMatveev edited as you requested

Answer (score 13):

You could try making the loop actually do something.  As it stands the compiler is quite rightly saying "This loop is doing nothing - I'll get rid of it".

So you could try a construct I use frequently:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    asm volatile ("nop");
}
```

Note: not all targets for the gcc compiler use the same inline assembly syntax - you may need to tweak it for your target.

Comment: Your solution seems much more elegant than mine... maybe mine is better when PRECISE cycle count is requires? I mean, the whole for thing is not guaranteed to be compiled in a certain way, is it?

Comment: The simple fact it's using C means you can't guarantee cycles.  If you need precise cycle counting then ASM is the only way to go.  I mean, you get different timing with the C loop if you have -funroll-loops enabled than if you don't, etc.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought. When doing HW delays with high enough i values (100 or more) I guess your solution yields virtually the same results while enhancing readability.

Answer (score 6):

Yes you could assume that. If you declare variable i as volatile you tell the compiler not to optimise on i.

Comment: That's not entirely true in my opinion.

Comment: Unfortunately this tells to compiler not only about optimization way but also force one to allocate the variable `i` in the RAM so my code become significantly bigger and slower. In my case each CPU tick is worthy so I'd like to find a way to control optimization inline if possible.

Comment: @VladimirCravero, what do you mean by saying that? Could you make more clear?

Comment: What I meant is that I would not be so sure about what a compiler does. Declaring a variable volatile tells the compiler that it might change somewhere else so it really should make that while.

Comment: This is a correct answer. Note that putting `i` in a register is already an optimization, therefore @Roman 's first comment is a misunderstanding.

Comment: @Roman Matveev `register unsigned char volatile i __asm__("r1");` maybe?

Comment: Declaring `i` as volatile solves everything. This is guaranteed by the C standard 5.1.2.3. A conforming compiler must not optimize away those loops if `i` is volatile. Luckily, GCC is a conforming compiler. There are unfortunately many would-be C compilers that don't conform to the standard, but that's irrelevant for this particular question. There is absolutely no need for inline assembler.

Answer (score 1):

After the first loop `i` is a constant. The initialization of `i` and the loop do nothing but produce a constant value. Nothing in the standard specifies that this loop must be compiled as-is. The standard does not say anything about timing either. The compiled code must behave as if the loop was present and it does. You can't reliably tell that this optimization was performed under the standard (timing does not count).

The second loop should be deleted as well. I consider it to be a bug (or a missing optimization) that it is not. After the loop `i` is constant zero. The code should be replaced with setting `i` to zero.

I think GCC keeps `i` around purely for the reason that you perform an (opaque) port access might affect `i`.

Use

```
asm volatile ("nop");
```

to trick GCC into believing that the loop does something.